# How to connect device over Wifi in VScode on Mac to debug Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code, wifi

I would like to be able to use **WIFI** to debug my Flutter app on VScode. I am using a mac and would not like to use the connection via USB

Comment: https://help.famoco.com/developers/dev-env/adb-over-wifi/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated May 2023 answer:**

**Google released Flutter 3.10 in the Google IO event, after this Update, we can debug our Flutter app wirelessly in real-time with IOS devices.**

after testing this feature, I still prefer to use the simulator because it's faster than a real device.
anyway, it was an interesting update.

---

**Old answer:**
You can't debug wireless in Visual Studio Code with iPhone and Mac.

You should run your project with Xcode to use the wireless option, but you lose the hot reload option after that.

**So, it's impossible to debug an app with hot reload and wireless at the same time :(**

To run the Flutter project with Xcode :

1. Open your project in **VSCode**
2. Click right on **iOS folder**
3. Select the `Open in Xcode` option
4. Xcode will run your `iOS Runner`
5. If you have any errors in Xcode - see this [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices) from the Flutter documentation

Comment: Flutter 3.10 allow it ! check out https://medium.com/@mfqscode/how-to-debug-wirelessly-on-flutter-with-an-ios-device-5ea1ff55adf4

Comment: Is anyone else having an issue with this on iOS 17? It works but no logs :(